# Why box (3) isn't possible and why box (4) is possible?

Tags: dice

The figure given on the left hand side is folded to form a box. Choose from the alternatives (1), (2), (3) and (4) the boxes that is similar to the box formed.

[image: Dice]

Source: [IndiaBix](https://www.indiabix.com/verbal-reasoning/dice/discussion-203)

I understood that box (1) and (2) are possible from given figure but I can't understand why box (3) isn't possible and how box (4) is possible?
To solve this question, we are generally given time of less than 2 minutes. How to solve this question with such a less time. Any tips in solving these type of questions fastly?

Comment: I think it might be helpful for you to physically try a few of these - actually print or draw the design on a piece of paper so that you can fold it and hold it in your hand. Doing it with a physical object might help you be able to visualize new ones.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the [Terms & Conditions](https://www.indiabix.com/about/privacy-policy.php) prohibit sharing: "The pages may not be redistributed or reproduced in any way, shape, or form without the written permission of www.IndiaBIX.com.". This violates our policy on puzzles shared against their creators' wishes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a (slightly crude, low-resolution) drawing of how the cube will fold:

[image]

Comment: (First version of this answer had a particularly silly mistake on my part - thanks @Chris and @​hdsdv for pointing it out!)

Answer (score 2):

In the unfolded version, the two black and white sides share a vertex to which the diagonal line arrives. It is also easy to see that the other shared vertex will have to be "only white"; the "upper left" vertices of each side (as seen in the unfolded image) will meet.

In (3), the two sides share two vertices:

- One in which one side has the diagonal line, but the other side has a "only white" part.
- One in which one side has the diagonal line, but the other side has a "only black" part.

Since it does not comply with the rules that we can observe from the unfolded dice, they are not the same dice.

Comment: Easier might be to talk about the edge that the two coloured faces share. Both have white along that edge.